# ADB No Device Found Android

Tags: android, adb

I found Kitkat version allow to record screen using adb commands, So i am trying to record video using adb shell command with below command.

Official Reference [this](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/jKmc7pRvfpx)

$ adb shell screenrecord/sdcard/video.mp4

i am using HTC Desire 620g , Driver is updated, USB debugging is checked, it's connected to windows system with MTP Mode.

also tried Revoke USB debugging authorisations.

but still cmd shows this strange behavior ..!

How to solve it..?

[image]

Comment: if you are already connected in the shell, `adb devices` of course wont show any devices. To use screenrecord from the command line, type the following:

`adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4`

Comment: Thanks @nicandris , i didn't notice the space between screenrecord and filepath. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space between **screenrecord** and the file path:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/recording.mp4
```

Then to download the file:

```
adb pull /sdcard/recording.mp4
```